# Case and CPU fans would randomly spin slowly or stopping alltogether

Tags: kubuntu, cpu, fan, overheating, temperature

My case and CPU fans would randomly stop spinning, or spin down (few hundred RPM) then stopping completely. It occurs every few days, the most recent event occurred approximately 1hr after resuming from sleep. The other two times were before I upgraded and was on Kubuntu 23.04 with kernel 6.2.0-36.37, happened while playing TF2. Very shocking to be gaming then feeling something is wrong and finding out your CPU temp is pegged to 90 degrees C. Usually putting the PC to sleep and waking it up immediately is enough to get them running normally again. Tried going into the BIOS and checking the fan curves, but nothing there is abnormal. (Fan stopping not allowed and base speed is 50% up to 50C then increasing to 100% at 65C.)

There are also times where one or more fans will be stuck at a fixed RPM and it would fail to ramp up with the CPU temp.

Has anyone encountered this bug? It's my first time encountering this issue and I am lost on where to start, so apologies on the lack of details. If anyone could give me pointers on how to diagnose and solve this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Currently running:

- Kubuntu 23.10
- Kernel: 6.5.0-10-generic
- Plasma 5.27.8
- Frameworks 5.110.0
- Motherboard: Asus Prime x470 Pro
- BIOS: 6202 (AGESA version ComboV2PI 1.2.0.A)
- CPU: AMD 5800X3D

Note: Fans are detected by System Monitor, which is what I'm using to check CPU temps and fan RPM.

The output of `sudo sensors` via `sudo sensors-detect` if it is useful:

```
asus_wmi_sensors-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
CPU Core Voltage:          1.27 V  
+12V Voltage:             12.23 V  
+5V Voltage:               4.99 V  
3VSB Voltage:              3.31 V  
CPU Fan:                  934 RPM
Chassis Fan 1:            698 RPM
Chassis Fan 2:            880 RPM
Chassis Fan 3:            940 RPM
AIO Pump:                   0 RPM
Water Pump:                 0 RPM
CPU OPT:                  969 RPM
CPU Temperature:          +38.0°C  
Motherboard Temperature:  +29.0°C  
Chipset Temperature:      +45.0°C  
Tsensor 1 Temperature:   +216.0°C  

asusec-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
CPU Core:      1.24 V  
CPU_Opt:      969 RPM
Chipset:      +45.0°C  
CPU:          +38.0°C  
Motherboard:  +29.0°C  
T_Sensor:     -40.0°C  
VRM:          +20.0°C  
CPU:           7.00 A  

nvme-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
Composite:    +39.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +84.8°C)
                       (crit = +84.8°C)
Sensor 1:     +39.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)
Sensor 2:     +34.9°C  (low  = -273.1°C, high = +65261.8°C)

ucsi_source_psy_3_00081-i2c-3-08
Adapter: NVIDIA GPU I2C adapter
in0:           0.00 V  (min =  +0.00 V, max =  +0.00 V)
curr1:         0.00 A  (max =  +0.00 A)

k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
Tctl:         +39.8°C  
Tccd1:        +34.2°C
```

Weirdly, `sudo pwmcontrol` gives the following output, despite my fans are Noctua A15 PWM and Be Quiet Silent Wings 3 PWM High-speed

```
/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed
```

Comment: I believe the error is saying that `asus_wmi_sensors` does not have pwm functionality.  Asus boards usually come with a Nuvoton Super I/O.  I would run `sensors-detect` and watch the Super I/O section to see if it finds anything, keep an eye out for errors there.

Comment: It did find ` `ITE IT8665E Super IO Sensors' ` but with the note `(address 0x290, driver to-be-written')`. I found [this](https://github.com/frankcrawford/it87) which has my chipset, but don't know if overriding the `it87.c` package that came with Kubuntu (but does not support ITE IT8665E) would be a good idea.

Comment: Scratch that "don't know if overriding it would be a good idea" part. I `git clone` it and installed it using `sudo make dkms` but the OS isn't picking it up, and don't know where I went wrong, so I removed it using `sudo make dkms_clean` just to be safe.

Comment: I assume you were getting your info from https://github.com/lm-sensors/lm-sensors/issues/195.  This thread is 4 years old and the github driver mods are even older.  I'm honestly surprised this isn't working with the latest kernel.  I do find a few other sources online regarding building and installing the driver yourself from github...but you have to do it after every kernel upgrade.

Comment: That's the one. It seems like the sensor `ITE IT8665E` was never actually integrated into the mainstream Linux kernel. Could you link me to the sources you've mentioned, if you still have them? I doubt I have the technical skill to build a driver, but I'm willing to check them out. Thank you!

Comment: I mainly just searched for `ITE "IT8665E" Super IO Sensors`

Comment: Seems you will likely need to add `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX='acpi_enforce_resources=lax'` to the grub config and rebuild it as well if you haven't already done that.